# connect LKVM vms over bridge

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, bridge

I'm using lightweight VM [lkvm](http://git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/will/kvmtool.git) which creates `tun` interfaces on the host. Now I want to connect two instances of `lkvm` over bridge interface, similar to what other VMs do:

```
               VM1                          VM2
          +----------+                 +-----------+
          |          |                 |           |
tap0 -----+eth0  eth1+--tap1-----tap2--+eth0   eth1+--tap3-
          |          |                 |           |
          +----------+                 +-----------+
```

- both VMs have routing enabled, and rp_filter disabled (not sure it's needed, but I read it somewhere, so disabled just in case)
- both VMs have relevant routes installed
- both VMs have correct IP addresses set on the interfaces
- bridge interface was created on host with `ip` tool, set up and running, `tap1` and `tap2` are added in the bridge (no IP addresses were added on `tap1` and `tap2` or bridge device -- not sure if it matters)
- enabled IP forwarding on the host
- subnets as follows
   VM1 eth0 20.20.20.2/24
       eth1 30.30.30.2/24
   VM2 eth0 30.30.30.3/24
       eth1 40.40.40.2/24

However it doesn't work for some reasons. I can't `ping` from VM1 eth1->tap1->br->tap2->eth0 (although I see packets on tap1 and bridge device, but not on tap2) or the other way around from VM2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you double-check [br_netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is *not* enabled on the host? either the `br_netfilter` module is not loaded, or if it is, `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` set to 0 (same for `bridge-nf-call-arptables`): your bridge is perhaps filtering using host's iptables... if it was, does the behaviour change once disabled?